# composing a SQL query with a date offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to do this:

```
select * from table 
where ChangingDate(this is a column which has date and time) = today's date + 1
```

I am a learner of SQL, and I am bad at date formats. I appreciate if someone can help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return tomorrow's data

```
WHERE ChangingDate > = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
and ChangingDate < dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())+2, 0)
```

This will return today's data

```
WHERE ChangingDate > = dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())+0, 0)
and ChangingDate < dateadd(dd, datediff(dd, 0, getdate())+1, 0)
```

See also [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

Answer (score 6):

There's a trick with datetimes in databases - you almost never want an = comparison, because as you saw they also include a time component.  Instead, you want to know if it falls inside a range that includes the entire day.  Sql Server 2008 has a new `date` type that helps with this, but until you upgrade, do it like this:

```
WHERE (ChangingDate >= dateadd(dd,1, datediff(dd,0, getDate())) 
       AND ChangingDate < dateadd(dd,2, datediff(dd,0, getDate())))
```

You can do an equals comparison if you are *certain* that all the records have a 0-value (or other known value) for the time component in that column.  What you don't want to do is truncate the column, because that means doing extra work per-record (slow) and will break your index (very slow).

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ChangingDate)) = SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @datetimecolumn)) gives just the date portion of the datetime.

Comment: Function around the column is not sargable, take a look at http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/only-in-a-database-can-you-get-1000-impr

Comment: @Ram, you should accept one of the answers by @SQLMenace or @Joel. They will perform better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try something like

```
select * from table where columndate=GetDate() + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the DATEPART function to find where the column date has the same year, month, day regardless of time of day:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(Month, Date) = DATEPART(Month, @SomeDate) 
AND DATEPART(Day, Date) = DATEPART(Day, @SomeDate) 
AND DATEPART(Year, Date) = DATEPART(Year, @SomeDate)
```

Otherwise, you want to use DateAdd like the other posters.

Comment: Not sargable, take a look at http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/only-in-a-database-can-you-get-1000-impr